# Uniswap V3 Oracle library: consult always crashes. Trying to get reliable oracle of Ethereum price in USDC

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, oracles, uniswapv3

```
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/main/contracts/libraries/OracleLibrary.sol";

  function poolAddress() public view returns (address) {
    return 0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8;
  }    

  function getEthPriceTick() public view returns (int24 arithmeticMeanTick, uint128 harmonicMeanLiquidity) {
    return OracleLibrary.consult(poolAddress(), 32);
  }
```

the pool address is the USDC-WETH pool.

Trying this on Remix, the crash happens, I click "Jump to where the crash happened"

```
  uint32[] memory secondsAgos = new uint32[](2);
        secondsAgos[0] = secondsAgo;
        secondsAgos[1] = 0;

        (int56[] memory tickCumulatives, uint160[] memory secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128s) =
            IUniswapV3Pool(pool).observe(secondsAgos); //<<<<HERE
```

Calling this function on Etherscan seems to work fine.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8#code

How do I make this function call in Solidity?
Is there a better way to get a reliable Ethereum USDC price oracle on-chain?

[image: Observe 32]

[image: Observe 32, 0]

Comment: How are you making the call from Remix? Do you deploy your own contract? Do you call the pool directly? Are you using a ganache mainnet fork?

Comment: I am making the call with their execute call using web3. I own the contract yes pool directly yes, Ropsten fork.